# Load html data with AJAX in Sencha touch when panel is shown

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a TabPanel with a Tabbar and four panels inside. I want to load the HTML content for the fourth panel with an AJAX call when the panel becomes visible.

The AJAX function fetches the data from the server and places it inside the panel, which uses the panel update function. The problem is how to call this function when the panel becomes visible. A simplified version is:

```
Pages.Contact = new Ext.Panel({

    title: 'Contact',
    html: 'test data',
    iconCls: 'user',
    cls: 'cHome',

    activate: function () {
        Pages.Contact.update("my ajax data");
    }

});
```

When I go to my panel the body content is not affected. Does anyone know what goes wrong here? I've already tried to replace activate with render and show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
beforecardswitch:function(object, newCard, oldCard, index, anim) {
```

As shown by Ilya139 by with the object parameter as first parameter.

Then the index variable returns the correct cardnumber.

Answer (score 1):

To add event's listeners you need to do

```
    listeners: {
                activate: function(){
                 console.log('activate fired');
                } 
   },
```

But that's not the event you want to listen. It's better to listen for beforecardswitch on the TapPanel object, example:

```
    listeners: {
                beforecardswitch:function(newCard, oldCard, index, anim){
                  if(index == 3){
                     //loadJson and update card.
                      // you may want to use this also 
                      newCard.setLoading(true);
                      //and after the json request has finished set it to false.
                    }             
                }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

If I use:

            listeners: {
                beforecardswitch: function (newCard, oldCard, index, anim) {

                    console.log(index);

                    
                }
            },

The index is not a number but an object. Any ideas?

Comment: well output that to the console with `console.log(index);` and see what is for your card. Then put that in the if statement.

Comment: I did and it turned out to be the whole tab object, which looks the same as the newcard object.

Comment: check all the other params of the function.

Comment: also check the id of the tab object

Comment: I tried but the panel does not pick up the id defined: Pages.Contact = new Ext.Panel({  
    id: 'pContact',